# Java JFrame is very strange

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

When I am running this, JLabel is not visible, but when I resize window (with mouse) JLabel is showed. Why?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FrmTaoLogin extends JFrame {

  private JPanel pnlLeft = new JPanel();

  public FrmTaoLogin() {

    super();

    pnlLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    pnlLeft.add(new JLabel("test1"));
    getContentPane().add(pnlLeft,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(200, 200); 

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    FrmTaoLogin FrmLogin = new FrmTaoLogin();
    FrmLogin.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

Comment: for me, your example works fine. Java 1.6.0_17 on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It's a bad practice to subclass JFrame just to add components.

Comment: It worked fine for me, too, which is why I suspect that a threading problem.

Comment: Adding to @kdgregory's comment, the better practice would be to put your components into a `JPanel` and then to set that `JPanel` as the content pane of your toplevel container (`JFrame`).  Check out the Swing toplevel containers tutorial for more examples: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look like some of the L&F bugs in older Java VMs on newer OS. For example on Windows 7 the most problems are solved first with 1.6.0_17. You should start your program with a console. If you see some stacktraces in the event thread then it is a problem of an L&F bug.

Comment: Thanx to all, problem resolved. I change Windows theme and all working fine. I think that's Windows Aero and my NVIDIA GeForce FX5500 problem. This card official not working with windows Aero.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, this happens when you don't call Frame.pack().  It should work if you call 'pack()' as the last line of the constructor.

Comment: Actually, `setSize()` should have the effect of calling `pack()` and forcing the frame to lay itself out, shouldn't it?

Comment: `setSize()` just tells the frame what size it should be; you need to call `invalidate()` to tell it to recompute its components. However, calling `pack()` as the last step of frame construction is a better habit.

Comment: I take that back - `setSize()` does not (in)directly call `pack()`.  However, the OP's code worked for me on the first try without adding a call to `pack()`.  Adding a call to `pack()` after the `setSize()` actually had the *undesirable* effect of overriding the given size settings, making the window smaller than the 200x200 that the OP wished for.

Comment: With pack() all is ok, but window size is not 200x200. :(

Comment: with invalidate I have same effect. :(

Comment: @Joe Good question.  I'm not sure now and the Javadocs aren't very clear.  JFrame inherits pack() and setSize() from Window.  setSize() doesn't specify and pack() says:

"If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both of them are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window is validated after its size is being calculated."

I think the validate method (inherited from Container in the case of JFrame) isn't called from setSize() (it's an expensive call, IIRC), but now I'm not so sure.

You might be right about the threading.

Comment: @rodion Make sure to set minimum (or preferred depending on the LayoutManager) sizes for all of the Components in the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem here may have to do with trying to build and show your GUI components outside of the [Swing thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).

What if you change `main()` to invoke your GUI code on the Swing thread, like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FrmTaoLogin FrmLogin = new FrmTaoLogin();
            FrmLogin.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: with invokeLater I have same effect :(

Comment: If you still have the same problem after putting everything into the Swing thread, then I would try putting components in a JPanel and setting that JPanel as the content pane for your toplevel container instead of adding them to the toplevel container directly, as @kdgregory suggested in the comments above.

Comment: Thanx, but it is first, what i am trying :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to all, problem resolved. I change Windows theme and all working fine. I think that's Windows Aero and my NVIDIA GeForce FX5500 problem. This card official not working with windows Aero.